# Error al cargar archivos .sql

Tags: php, fileupload

Estoy tratando de cargar archivos con la función `upload`, pero cuando intento subir un archivo `.sql`, me sale un mensaje que dice:

> El tipo de archivo que esta tratando de subir no esta permito.

```
$config['upload_path']      = './doc_anexa';
$config['allowed_types']    = 'txt|doc|docx|sql|xls';
$config['overwrite']        = true;


$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);

    }else{
           $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

           $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);

        }
```

Comment: la función upload es de codeigniter no?

Comment: ¿qué framework y versión usas?

Comment: Estoy usandon Codeigniter y la versión es la 3.1.5, he buscado documentación sobre este error y no he encontrado nada, no se como solucionarlo.